# Entity Framework - how do I get the columns?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, asp.net-mvc-3

I wish to get a list of columns names, types and whether the column is a PK of a table object in Entity Framework.

How do I do this in C# (4.0) (ideally generically)?

The winning answer will be one that does it efficiently and most importantly generically.

Comment: For what use, and in which context? I mean, with EF you have Entities, so why not for example simply reflect your model-entities and finding out PKs by naming conventions that might be there?

Comment: Why has my post been voted down?  If you think it's a bad question - please comment and I'll explain more rather than just deface my post.

Comment: @johnny Yes - I am trying to build a where clause using expressions. I have a dynamically build where clause with dynamically built lambda expressions adding a .contains for each column - but I need the table properties to both build a default collection of property names and to verify a custom passing of field names.  Everything else works fine so far - just missing the EF table columns

Comment: @Femaref - please explain reason for editing of post?

Comment: The part edited out didn't add anything to the question at hand and in general, are frowned upon on SO anyway.

Comment: Thank you Femaref - I understand now - I was being silly - sorry.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, why wouldn't do simple Reflection of your model do the job?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all names of properties in an Entity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851274/how-to-get-all-names-of-properties-in-an-entity)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it - I used a linq based reflection query:

```
IEnumerable<FieldList> properties = from p in typeof(T).GetProperties()
                                    where (from a in p.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                    where a is EdmScalarPropertyAttribute   
                                    select true).FirstOrDefault()
```

Sorted!
Thanks for the suggestions all.

FYI - I am creating a dynamic where clause using LINQ, dynamic lambda expressions to build e.g. search which will automatically search through all columns by default.  But I also needed the column names to verify because I will allow this to be overridden and these calls will be done via javascript ajax post whose input cannot be trusted - so needed to verify the column names.

I used the above to place the results into a custom object with properties called FieldName, FieldType, PrimaryKey. Ta daaa.

Customise it further with

```
IEnumerable<FieldList> properties = from p in typeof(T).GetProperties()
                                    where (from a in p.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                    where a is EdmScalarPropertyAttribute
                                    select true).FirstOrDefault()
                                    select new FieldList
                                    {
                                       FieldName = p.Name,
                                       FieldType = p.PropertyType,
                                       FieldPK = p.GetCustomAttributes(false).Where(a => a is EdmScalarPropertyAttribute && ((EdmScalarPropertyAttribute)a).EntityKeyProperty).Count() > 0
                                     };
```

Comment: @boomhauer see answer below for non reflection method

Answer (score 9):

if you want only column names then ,i got the best answer :
 `var properties = (from t in typeof(YourTableName).GetProperties()
                               select t.Name).ToList();
             var name= properties[0];`

Comment: I donot have ability or I would give you 100 up.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to use reflection, see answer [here](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET24). Replace entity name below with your entity name

```
var cols = from meta in ctx.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace)
                       .Where(m=> m.BuiltInTypeKind==BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType)
                    from p in (meta as EntityType).Properties
                       .Where(p => p.DeclaringType.Name == "EntityName")
                   select new
                      {
                       PropertyName = p.Name,
                       TypeUsageName = p.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name, //type name
                       Documentation = p.Documentation != null ?               
                                       p.Documentation.LongDescription : null //if primary key
        };
```

Comment: What's ctx and how do I get a handle to it?  Is that for Model or Datbase first because I am using Code First

Comment: in 3.5 its the objectcontext instance, in later EF versions its the instance of dbcontext you are using. example using var ctx = new MyEntities....

Comment: I'm on .Net 4.5 EF Code FIrst and my DBContext does not have the MetadataWorkspace property

Comment: can you convert dbcontext to object context: ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext; or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059900/convert-dbcontext-to-objectcontext-for-use-with-gridview

Comment: Thanks that worked
var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)this;
            var childNavProperties = adapter.ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace)
                    .Where(item => item.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType)
                    .SelectMany(item => ((EntityType)item).NavigationProperties)

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still looking, Here's how I did it.
This is an extension method for the DBContext that takes a type and returns physical column names and their properties.

This utilizes object context to get physical columns list, then uses the "PreferredName" metadata property to map each column it its property.

Since it uses object context, it initiates a database connection, so the first run will be slow depending on the complexity of the context.

```
public static IDictionary<String, PropertyInfo> GetTableColumns(this DbContext ctx, Type entityType)
{
    ObjectContext octx = (ctx as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
    EntityType storageEntityType = octx.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace)
        .Where(x => x.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType).OfType<EntityType>()
        .Single(x => x.Name == entityType.Name);

    var columnNames = storageEntityType.Properties.ToDictionary(x => x.Name,
        y => y.MetadataProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "PreferredName")?.Value as string ?? y.Name);

    return storageEntityType.Properties.Select((elm, index) =>
            new {elm.Name, Property = entityType.GetProperty(columnNames[elm.Name])})
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Property);
}
```

To use it, just create a helper static class, and add above function; then it's as simple as calling

```
var tabCols = context.GetTableColumns(typeof(EntityType));
```

Comment: This is the best answer as it returns the physical column names, which are not necessarily the same as the EF property names.

Answer (score 1):

```
typeof(TableName).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Although it works great for column names but is still returning also foreign keys and relations names which are not always great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a a code sample for you, but just so that you're pointed in the right direction, you might want to look into using the Sql Management Objects (SMO); you can use this to get an object hierarchy for an Sql Server instance, which you can then enumerate and pick out the information you need.

Have a look at this set of tutorials to get you started with the programming - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SMO_Tutorial_1.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SMO_Tutorial_2.aspx

Comment: No No - i want to examine the ef table objects in code not the sql tables. I.e. i need the property names of the ef class generated when you add a table to the ef diagram

Comment: @Dan B - The "admin" removed the text `Ready, steady....GO! Thanks, Dan.`. How has the post lost part of it's meaning with this change?

Comment: @Yakimych - my mistake then - I presumed there was more. I think i had a sentance in, and then I removed it but I thought it was in. How did you find that out? I would be keen on knowing the sort of things we're not supposed to write as that doesn't seem to be in any way detrimental to the very short post. I have now removed my inaccurate comment.  Can you tell who voted my post down?

Comment: @Dan B - If you click on where it says he edited it, you can see an edit history. It shows you what he changed.

Comment: @Dan B - Furthermore, if you don't agree with the edit of your post for some reason, you can revert it. And no, you cannot see who upvotes or downvotes your posts. I agree with you, however, that the user who makes a downvote should leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: Great thanks for the excellent info Yakimych.  I will keep in mind and thank you for educating me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DB First or Model First, open up the .edmx file EF generated in a text editor. It's just an XML file, and it contains everything you need. Here's an example from a model of mine. Note that I'm using Oracle's EF driver, so yours won't look identical (but it should be pretty close).

```
        <EntityType Name="STRATEGIC_PLAN">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Type="Decimal" Name="Id" Nullable="false" Precision="8" Scale="0" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="None" />
          <Property Type="Decimal" Name="CreatedById" Nullable="false" Precision="8" Scale="0" />
          <Property Type="DateTime" Name="CreatedDate" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Type="Decimal" Name="DepartmentId" Nullable="false" Precision="4" Scale="0" />
          <Property Type="String" Name="Name_E" Nullable="false" MaxLength="2000" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
          <Property Type="String" Name="Name_F" MaxLength="2000" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
          <Property Type="Decimal" Name="UpdatedById" Precision="8" Scale="0" />
          <Property Type="DateTime" Name="UpdatedDate" />
          <Property Type="DateTime" Name="Timestamp" Nullable="false" Precision="6" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="AnnualPlans" Relationship="StrategicPlanningModel.R_51213" FromRole="STRATEGIC_PLAN" ToRole="STRAT_ANNUAL_PLAN" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="Department" Relationship="StrategicPlanningModel.R_51212" FromRole="STRATEGIC_PLAN" ToRole="DEPARTMENT" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="CreatedBy" Relationship="StrategicPlanningModel.R_51210" FromRole="STRATEGIC_PLAN" ToRole="STAFF" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="UpdatedBy" Relationship="StrategicPlanningModel.R_51211" FromRole="STRATEGIC_PLAN" ToRole="STAFF" />
          <Property Type="String" Name="Desc_E" MaxLength="2000" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
          <Property Type="String" Name="Desc_F" MaxLength="2000" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="Goals" Relationship="StrategicPlanningModel.R_51219" FromRole="STRATEGIC_PLAN" ToRole="STRATEGIC_PLAN_GOAL" />
        </EntityType>
```

You can use an XML parser to parse the file and get what you need. The .edmx file contains data on both the entities and the SQL tables, so you'll need to make sure you're getting the right part of it to get what you want.

Comment: That's cool - I will definitely come back to this but I'm still on 4.0 and I am not looking at code first (yet) just normal EF 4.0.

Comment: Then it'll work. :) Code First is the case where it won't work because there is no edmx file in code first.

Comment: COOL! Sorry - sleepy after lunch LOL  I will take a look and let you know how I get one - CHEERS!

Answer (score 0):

To get only columns names without table relations eg. foreign key.

```
var columnNames = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(p => p.CanRead && !p.GetGetMethod()!.IsVirtual)
            .Select(property => property.Name)
            .ToList();
```

In DB context relations are usually marked as virtual objects (unless in my Postgres test).

Comment: OF course you can't rely on the virtual modifier. Also, see "and whether the column is a PK". It's impossible to do this without accessing EF's own metadata.