# Entity Framework - getting a table's column names as a string array

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

If I'm using EF 5 and Database first to generate a .edmx model of my database, how do I get a list of an entity's columns?

```
using (var db = new ProjectNameContext())
{
    // string[] colNames = db.Users.
}
```

What I'm looking for is colNames[0] == "Id", colNames[1] == "FirstName", etc.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17311697/261050

Answer (score 46, accepted):

How about:

```
var names = typeof(User).GetProperties()
                        .Select(property => property.Name)
                        .ToArray();
```

Of course, this can be used for any type, not just an EF table.

Comment: This is not accurate. Properties can be mapped to column names that are not the same as the property name via specific configurations but also via conventions.

Comment: Adding to what @GeorgeMauer wrote: EF allows for props suffixed with "Id" to automatically map to an object of the same name w/o the Id suffix, which is the actual column name. Thus if you had "object Name" and "int NameId" there would be a "Name" column of type int, but no NameId column.

Comment: @davi_i how do i iterate through a list of tables ad get the column names of the tables. I want to set the table name dynamically instead of saying typeof(User). Can that be done?

Comment: @GayaneeWijayasekara Hey, I'd ask a new question. That way more people will be able to see your question to answer it and it may help someone else in the future.

Comment: This looks like the property name, is that the same thing as the column name?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I have answered below for the column names different.

Answer (score 11):

```
var res = typeof(TableName).GetProperties()
                        .Select(property => property.Name)
                        .ToArray();
```

OR

```
var res = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TableName))
                           .GetProperties().Select(x => x.Relational().ColumnName)
                           .ToList();

var index = 0;    
var propertyInfo = res[index].PropertyInfo;

var columnName = res[index].Relational().ColumnName;
var propertyName = propertyInfo.Name;
var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(sourceObject); // NEED OBJECT TO GET VALUE
```

Comment: Could you please clarify, what is the difference between the two and what the latter does differently? Is the result the same?

Comment: The latter will give you the actual name of the column while the first will only give you the name of the property. So if property `foo` is mapped to column `bar` then the latter will give you `"bar"`. So the latter is the actual answer to the question, the accepted answer isn't. It requires EF Core 2.x though.

Comment: Hi, I think the answer should be updated : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42467710