# Getting all column names of an entity in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to get a list of all actual column names in my EF entity. I explicitly *don't* want the navigation properties, though. I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704364/entity-framework-getting-a-tables-column-names-as-a-string-array) question, which is pretty straight forward, but ignores the second requirement.

My first approach was, to filter the property types with a `Linq` where clause. I could check for `IEnumerable` or `Lazy<T>`. But I guess, that `Lazy<T>` doesn't implement `IEnumerable` and I haven't found a way to do a generic `Lazy` check. Is this even the best approach, or are there any better?

Comment: Il you are using EF6, this should help https://romiller.com/2015/08/05/ef6-1-get-mapping-between-properties-and-columns/

Comment: are you using EF Core?

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev No, good old .net Framework.