# Entity Framework 6 - Get PK Column Generically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I am using EF 6.1 and link to entities (OData).  I need to get the name of the Primary Key column(s) in a generic fashion.

I thought I had found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056597/entity-framework-how-do-i-get-the-columns)

Using this bit of code:

```
IEnumerable<FieldList> properties = from p in typeof(T).GetProperties()
                                where (from a in p.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                where a is EdmScalarPropertyAttribute
                                select true).FirstOrDefault()
                                select new FieldList
                                {
                                   FieldName = p.Name,
                                   FieldType = p.PropertyType,
                                   FieldPK = p.GetCustomAttributes(false).Where(a => a is EdmScalarPropertyAttribute && ((EdmScalarPropertyAttribute)a).EntityKeyProperty).Count() > 0
                                 };
```

The code runs fine, but does not return any values because none of the property attributes is of type EdmScalarPropertyAtttribute.

Everything is a System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute.  I cannot find anything in the GetCustomAttributes or other methods and properties that would help me find the PK.

How can I find the PK of a table in EF 6.1?

Comment: [Entity Framework Code First Find Primary Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253943/entity-framework-code-first-find-primary-key)

Comment: Thanks, Yuliam, but my context is a System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.  It cannot be converted to an IObjectContextAdapter.