# How to get the column names dynamically for a table that is part of Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I can create a dynamic query but as it stands now the column needs to be typed in. I would prefer to allow selection from a combobox.

I can get the tables with this

```
using (var dbContext = new SalesEntities())
{
    var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

    var tables = metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.SSpace)
                .GetItems<EntityContainer>()
                .Single()
                .BaseEntitySets;

    foreach (var table in tables)
    {
        cboTable.Items.Add(table.Name );
    }
}
```

And I eventually run the query with this (It would be nice if there was a way I can generalize this code so it is not reproduced for each table)

```
List<Sales_Regions> srsl;

var query1 = SC.Sales_Regions.Where(txtField.Text + " = @0",  txtValue.Text);
srsl = query1.ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = srsl;
```

Looking at this post ([Entity Framework - how do I get the columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056597/entity-framework-how-do-i-get-the-columns)) I tried this:

```
IEnumerable<FieldList> properties = from p in typeof(T).GetProperties()
    where (from a in p.GetCustomAttributes(false)
        where a is EdmScalarPropertyAttribute
        select true).FirstOrDefault()
    select new FieldList
    {
        FieldName = p.Name,
        FieldType = p.PropertyType.ToString (),
        FieldPK = p.GetCustomAttributes(false).Where(a => a is EdmScalarPropertyAttribute && ((EdmScalarPropertyAttribute)a).EntityKeyProperty).Count() > 0
    };
```

And I created a class to go with it (don't know if this is wrong or not)

```
class FieldList
{
    public string FieldName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string FieldType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public bool FieldPK
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

But I get an error

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried several things but the fact of the matter is I do not know what goes there.

This one may actually be better, I got the code to work, but I don't know how to get the data out of cols.

```
var cols = from meta in objctx.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace)
        .Where(m => m.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType)
    from p in (meta as EntityType).Properties
        .Where(p => p.DeclaringType.Name == cboTable.SelectedItem.ToString())
    select new
    {
        PropertyName = p.Name,
        TypeUsageName = p.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name, //type name
        Documentation = p.Documentation != null ? p.Documentation.LongDescription : null //if primary key
    };
```

It seems like I'm really close. Trying to be as dynamic as possible.

Comment: I don't see the point of your `FieldList` class. What is wrong with using the `PropertyInfo` class? It seems to have everything you'd need.

Comment: @Mr. Anderson, any clues on how to get what I need out of the PropertyInfo class?

Comment: Is it a compilation error? You probably copy pasted a generic function body. Instead of typeof(T) insert typeof(Sales_Regions).

Comment: @bubi, well if I have to hard code Sales_Regions that will make it useless.  It needs to be dynamic.  So it looks like the third option is the only way for me since it accepts a variable (cboTable.SelectedItem).  But I can not figure out how to get the data out of cols.  Perhaps I should make a new question?