# Auditing Entity Framework Actions

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Be gentle, Its my first post so sorry if I don't get the terminology right first time.

In `Entity Framework` I need to write some **auditing code**.

I have a context class which inherits `DbContext` which has my Database.
`SetInitializer` and My `DbSets` for each entity.

I also have an override of SaveChanges where I am doing the auditing.

There are 3 levels of auditing, **None**, **Basic** and **AllProperties** and each Entity has a different property assigned to it, in this case I am trying to do an AllProperties audit.

This works for `EntityState.Modified` where I am using `GetModifiedProperties` in a foreach to write a new record for each property amended

But I am having trouble doing the same for `EntityState.Added`, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent `GetNewProperties` that I can loop through.

```
case AuditType.AllProperties:
{
  if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
  {
    foreach (var propertyName in entry.GetModifiedProperties()
      .Where(propertyName => propertyName != "Id" && propertyName != "RowVersion"))
      {
        var original = entry.OriginalValues;
        var oldValue = original.GetValue(original.GetOrdinal(propertyName)).ToString();

        var current = entry.CurrentValues;
        var newValue = current.GetValue(current.GetOrdinal(propertyName)).ToString();

        //if (oldValue != newValue) // probably not necessary
        //{

        AuditTrails.Add(new AuditTrail
          {
            DomainId = domainId,
            Controller = "",
            Action = "",
            EntityType = entry.Entity.GetType().Name,
            EntityId = entityId,
            Property = propertyName,
            Before = oldValue,
            After = newValue
           });
       }
     }
     else
     {

       AuditTrails.Add(new AuditTrail
         {
           DomainId = domainId,
           Controller = "",
           Action = "",
           EntityType = entry.Entity.GetType().Name,
           EntityId = entityId,
           EntityValue = entry.Entity.ToString(),
           Property = "",
           Before = "",
           After = entry.State.ToString()
         });
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Just guessing but new record they would all be new properties. So is there a GetAllProperties or GetProperties? [maybe this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851274/how-to-get-all-names-of-properties-in-an-entity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below now works for me at the moment

```
if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < entry.CurrentValues.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            var propertyName = entry.CurrentValues.DataRecordInfo.FieldMetadata[i].FieldType.Name;

                            if (propertyName == "Id") continue;
                            if (propertyName == "RowVersion") continue;

                            AuditTrails.Add(new AuditTrail
                                                {
                                                    DomainId = domainId,
                                                    Controller = "",
                                                    Action = entry.State.ToString(),
                                                    EntityType = entityType,
                                                    EntityId = entityId,
                                                    EntityValue = "", //entityValue,
                                                    Property = propertyName,
                                                    Before = "",
                                                    After = entry.CurrentValues[i].ToString(),
                                                });
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call `entry.OriginalValues`, you have access to the `PropertyNames` property, which will give you a list of all the properties. Since it's a new entry, they are all new anyway.