# Entity Framework get properties including some values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I have a method which iterates through all the properties of an object. I am logging those properties:

```
Object obj = entry.Entity;
Type type = obj.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

 foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
 {
     oldData.AppendFormat("{0}={1} || ", property.Name, property.GetValue(obj, null));
 }
```

Now this is working fine but on my table log, it is also writing this properties below:

```
- PremiumReference=System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1[Data.Premium]
- EntityState=Deleted
- EntityKey=System.Data.EntityKey
```

Any ideas how I can filter this properties?

Comment: Which version of EF are you using? In old versions (EF 4), all model classes derived from EntityObject class that has EntityState and EntityKey properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue with this code below:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(pi => !(pi.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityObject))) && !(pi.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityReference))))
            .ToArray();
```

The `BindingFlags` did help but I do not also want the `EntityReference` and `EntityObject` so I needed to add the `where` clause.

[How to get all names of properties in an Entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851274/how-to-get-all-names-of-properties-in-an-entity)

Answer (score 2):

Every Entity in Entity Framework has a property with the enumeration `EntityState`. EF adds them to the object.

If you add an Object to EF it marks it as EntityState.Added.

Hope it helps.

See [Entity Framework EntityState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Lukas but this does not answer the question. I am well aware that every object in Ef has an `EntityState`, I just don't want them in my logs. This does not answer the question.

Comment: Ok sorry i did misunderstood you Question. Sorry :)

Comment: No worries, it happens :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in here

[BindingFlags-Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx)

Maybe it helps using the flag DeclaredOnly in combination with the other flags you need in your scenario to match your needs.